# Differential forms and integrability of subbundle

Tags: differential-forms, differential

first merry Christmas to the team.  Now let be $M$ a manifold of dimension $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Let be $\alpha_{1}, \alpha_{2}, ..., \alpha_{n-k}$ $n-k$ $1$-forms linearly independent in each points of $M$. I suppose those forms are smooth. For all $x \in M$, let be $P_{x} = \bigcap_{i = 1}^{n-k}Ker(\alpha_{i}(x))$ and $\omega = \alpha_{1} \wedge \alpha_{2} \wedge ... \wedge \alpha_{n-k}$. 
I shown $P$ is a subbundle of $TM$.

I would like to show that [for all $x \in M$ it exists $f \in C^{\infty}(M)$ such that $f(x) \neq 0$ and such that $d(f\omega) = 0$ on neighbourhood of $x$] if I suppose $P$ is integrable.

Here is the reason I made : 
Let be $x \in M$. Let be $U$ a small neighbourhood of  $x$ and $(a_{i})_{i \in <n-k+1, n>}$ 1-differentials forms  and $(X_{i})_{i \in <1, n>}$  smooth vectorial fields construct the following way : lets complete $(\alpha_{i}(x))_{i \in <1, n-k>}$ in a base $(\alpha_{i}(x))_{i \in <1, n>}$ of $T^{*}_{x}M$. We can suppose $U$ small enough such that it's the domain of a map $\phi$. For all $i \in <n-k+1, n>$, $\alpha_{i}(x) = \sum_{j = 1}^{n}a_{j}^{i}d(\phi_{j})(x)$. As the determinant is a continuous map we can suppose  $U$ small enough such that $\alpha_{i}(.) := d\beta_{i}(.)$(where $\beta_{i}(.) = \sum_{j = 1}^{n}a_{j}^{i}\phi_{j}(.)$) is such that for all $y \in U$, $(\alpha_{i}(x))_{i \in <1, n>}$ is a base of $T_{y}^{*}M$. Now we can construct $(X_{i})_{i \in <1, n>}$ smotth vectorial fields on $U$ such that $\alpha_{i}(X_{j}) = \delta_{ij}(1)$ on $U$.

Now, I wrote $[X_{i}, X_{j}] = \sum_{l = 1}^{n}c_{ij}^{l}X_{l}$ and using $(1)$ I show $d \alpha_{l} = -\sum_{i < j} c_{ij}^{l} \alpha_{i} \wedge \alpha_{j} (3)$.

As $P$ is integrable,  $c_{ij}^{h} \equiv 0$ on $U$ if  $i, j \in <n-k+1, n>$ and $h \in <1, n-k>(*)$. So using $(*)$$ d \omega = \sum_{l = 1}^{n-k}\epsilon_{l}' \omega \wedge \sum_{i \in <n-k +1, n>}c_{il}^{l} \alpha_{i}$ where $\epsilon_{l}' \in \{\pm 1\}(2)$. So in $(2)$, $d \omega = \omega \wedge \sum_{l = 1}^{n-k}\epsilon_{l}' \sum_{i \in <n-k +1, n>}c_{il}^{l} d\beta_{i}$. Let's considering  $f = e^{(-1)^{n-k} \times (\sum_{l = 1}^{n-k}\epsilon_{l}' \sum_{i \in <n-k +1, n>}c_{il}^{l} \beta_{i})}$ which is smooth and positive on $U$. So $d(f\omega) = (-1)^{n-k}f \times ((\sum_{l = 1}^{n-k}\epsilon_{l}' \sum_{i \in <n-k +1, n>}c_{il}^{l} d\beta_{i}) \wedge \omega - (\sum_{l = 1}^{n-k}\epsilon_{l}' \sum_{i \in <n-k +1, n>}dc_{il}^{l} \beta_{i} ) \wedge \omega) - f d\omega = (\sum_{l = 1}^{n-k}\epsilon_{l}' \sum_{i \in <n-k +1, n>}dc_{il}^{l} \beta_{i} ) \wedge \omega + f d\omega - f d\omega = (\sum_{l = 1}^{n-k}\epsilon_{l}' \sum_{i \in <n-k +1, n>}dc_{il}^{l} \beta_{i} ) \wedge \omega$

on $U$.

If I show $(\sum_{l = 1}^{n-k}\epsilon_{l}' \sum_{i \in <n-k +1, n>}dc_{il}^{l} \beta_{i} ) \wedge \omega = 0$ on $U$ I'll won.

I try to differentiate the expression $(3)$ but it doesn't give me informations. If the $c_{lj}^{l}$ could be constant. But I don't have freedom to choose them in constant in my construction.

Do you have ideas?

Thanks for all the answers and merry Christmas again.

Comment: I'll be honest and admit I didn't read everything you wrote. Do you know the equivalent criterion for integrability that $d\alpha_i\equiv 0\pmod{\langle \alpha_j\rangle}$? If so, that will tell you that $d\omega \equiv 0\pmod{\langle\omega\rangle}$. Does that help?

Answer (score 0):

thank you for your answer. The criterion you gave to me is the Froebenius theorem I use to get (2).

And at the end I get $d \omega = 0 mod (<\omega>)$ : more precisely I get $ d \omega = \omega \wedge \sum_{l = 1}^{n-k}\epsilon_{l}' \sum_{i \in <n-k +1, n>}c_{il}^{l} d\beta_{i} $ but then I can't conclude at the end.

If the $c_{il}^{l}$ where constants on $U$ I could conclude with the function $f$ I wrote.

Perhaps you have got an another idea?

I wish you a good day.